# ArgoCD Helm template of template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have argocd-apps that create two resources of the helm for me.
it looks like:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: "{{ $key }}"
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    name: "{{ $key }}"
spec:
  project: just-test
  sources:
  - repoURL: https://github.com/blabla.git
    targetRevision: "main"
    path: this_is/where_the_values_file_is
    helm:
      ignoreMissingValueFiles: true
      releaseName: test
      parameters:
      - name: secrets
        value: "{{ $val.secrets }}"
  - repoURL: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress.git
    targetRevision: "0.1.1"
    chart: nginx-ingress
    helm:
      ignoreMissingValueFiles: true
      releaseName: test2
      version: v3
  destination:
    name: "{{ $.Values.cluster_name }}"
    namespace: "{{ $val.namespace }}"
  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
    - Validate=false
    - CreateNamespace=true
    - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
    - PruneLast=true
    retry:
      limit: 5
      backoff:
        duration: 5s
        factor: 2
        maxDuration: 3m
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

it's should template 2 applications, 1 nginx and the other my app,
here is the template of my applications (k8s cm):

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
{{ .Values.secrets }}
```

this is the values i'm passing to .Values.secrts

```
secrets:
  - name: xxxx
    value: xxx
  - name: yyyy
    value: yyy
```

In the second tamplate I'm getting the values as a string map,

```
  [map[name:xxxx value:xxx]
  map[name:yyyy value:yyy]]
```

I'm trying to get a normal dict that i can work with, what i need to do to get values like a
regular dict -> $val.name, $val.value
thanks.

I've tried toYaml, toJson, fromYaml, fromJson, build a dict, and change the values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate over a dictionary you'll to use helm's [range function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data: 
  {{- range $k, $v := .Values.secrets }}
  {{ $v.name }}: {{ quote $v.value }}
  {{- end }}
```

Running `helm template .` will output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
  xxxx: "xxx"
  yyyy: "yyy"
```